# Custom font in swift 4 make Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I have to add custom font to my app. I added fonts to my project and listed infolist.

```
 enum Proxima: String {
        case regular = "Regular"
        func font(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
            return UIFont(name: "Proxima-\(rawValue)", size: size)!
        }
    }
```

**Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** while calling

```
self.headTitle.font = UIFont.Proxima.regular.font(size: 30)
```

**UPDATE**

I added the target and also checked the copy bundle resources all are correct but still i got same error.

[image]
[image]

[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ECKA.png)

Comment: Check these - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app and https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: Did you include it in `Info.plist` file with key `Fonts provided by application`

Comment: @Vishal16 yes i added

Comment: for regular font directly use "Proxima" . Xcode will use regular font by default.

Answer (score 8):

Be sure that your files are added to your target

Also, don't forget to add them into the "Font provided by application" section of the `Info.plist`

Answer (score 5):

If you follow this [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app) and still have problems it is most certain that the problem is with the font name. To check the correct font name, install the font on your Mac, and open it. Then click the desired font and then the "i" icon for more information:

[image]

Make sure that this is the name you use in both:

- Info.plist
- In your enum (the raw value)

[image]

[image]

PS: If you try to use licensed fonts, then it will not work with the method above. I tried to use Bariol (duh!), but it would not recognize them. I assume there is a way to integrate your license, but I did not spend the time to do it, I just switched to a Google Font instead.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have not added fonts into your target

Select your fonts and from right panel check the target

[image]

Comment: I already checked the target but its not working. Still i get the same error.

Comment: @Daliyachacko Try  to print  `UIFont.familyNames` make sure you got exact name

Comment: @Daliyachacko Are you able to see the font using Above method ?

Comment: UIFont.familyNames  not listing my font.

Comment: @Daliyachacko could you please post screen shot of info.plist file

Comment: I have added the image of info.plist. check it

Comment: @Daliyachacko it looks fine. make sure you have no extra space , If it is possible to share sample code ?. Or try other fonts and check that it is working or not

Answer (score 1):

Remove Regular for font because iOS uses a default font as regular try modifying code your code and It's working fine after that.

Ex:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
enum OpenSans: String {
    case regular = ""
    case semiBold = "-Semibold"
    func font(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "OpenSans\(rawValue)", size: size)!
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib..

    label1.font = OpenSans.regular.font(size: 30.0)

    label1.font = OpenSans.semiBold.font(size: 30.0)
}
```

If still you have a problem Please refer to this demo project

[FontDemo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OXvn2lue8rhbVaCy-JHsBHE7Lk5A9ctc)

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Identity and type and check does that font is added for project or not I am attaching ScreenShot for referral [select that from right side as I checked Playo on that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evE0g.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31870455)

Comment: No it does sometimes when people drag and drop fonts they missed to select add to target option and this happens with me that's why I posted that may someOne can find help from this

Answer (score 0):

**Try these**

- Add custom files in your project and also verify in Copy Bundle Resource in Build Phase
- Using this function you can check fonts available in your project. add this function in appDelegate and call it from didFinsihLaunching.

  ```
  func printFonts() {
    let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames
    for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
        print("------------------------------")
        print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
        let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
        print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
      }
    }
  ```
- If your custom font is available in printed fonts list then you can use.

Comment: Custom font is not listing. But i check the bundle resources and the font is there. I updated the question can you please check it.

Comment: Did you check with printFonts function? your font is available in it.

Comment: I had checked with the same font. and I m able to use this font.
`------------------------------
Font Family Name = [Proxima Nova]
Font Names = [["ProximaNova-Regular"]]
------------------------------`

Comment: I am using a new font file Proxima-Regular.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code to check available font in your project.

```
for fontFamilyName in UIFont.familyNames{
    for fontName in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontFamilyName){
        print("Family: \(fontFamilyName)     Font: \(fontName)") 
    }
}
```

See the output in your console, all the available fonts are printed here, check the actual font name of your provided fonts.

And use that font name for `UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 15)`

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 11.1, iOS 13.1

I did all things right, but one custom font was missing in the list of fonts (via `UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontFamilyName)`).

Then I reordered the missing font in Info.plist (Fonts provided by application) to the front and it worked, yay.

Maybe this helps someone.